# When package has same name as .py file inside the package, import X imports the module and not the package itself. How to avoid?

Tags: python, package, python-import

So the package Im constructing looks something like this:

```
Blur/
├── blur
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── blur.py
│   ├── funcs
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── face_funcs.py
│   │   └── funcs.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_blur.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── timer.py
└── setup.py
```

Doing `import blur` imports blur.py module, and not the whole package itself. If I change blur.py's name, then do the import, i get the whole package. Any way to get the whole package without changing blur.py's name?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the file path to the "Blur" folder in the import statement, that should force python to import the package, and not the .py file. I believe by default python looks for files ending in .py when importing.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it is not possible as a built-in Python mechanism, so changing the name would be your best bet.

There are, however, workarounds available, but in my opinion such solutions are rather ugly.

Here is an example:

```
import importlib
import os
import sys

def custom_import(repo_path, directory, package=False):
    absolute_path = repo_path if package else os.path.join(repo_path, directory)
    if os.path.exists(absolute_path):
        sys.path.insert(0, absolute_path)
        if package:
            imported = importlib.import_module(f'{directory}')
        else:
            imported = importlib.import_module(f'{directory}.{directory}')
        sys.path.pop(0)
        return imported
    raise ImportError(' No such package/module found')
```

Example use:

```
package = custom_import('D:\PycharmProjects\python-tools', 'roomba', package=True)
module = custom_import('D:\PycharmProjects\python-tools', 'roomba')


module.main()
```